# Correct way to use mongoose in Node

Tags: asynchronous, mongoose

All:

I am pretty new to MongoDB/Mongoose in Node.

I am not sure what is the correct way to import db connection, from the quickstart:

It uses it like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});
```

**One question** here is:

It binds error and open event to that connection after running

```
mongoose.connect
```

Why this still be able to catch open and error event **if the connecting finished before** db.on and db.once?(What I am not sure about here is: does that mongoose.connect actually send connect request to mongoDB server or just set some values to inside the mongoose OR the mongoose works like a promise?)

I want to use this as a node module to export to other module in node, so I just simply make a db.js:

> db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});

module.exports = mongoose;
```

And I use this db connection in test.js

> test.js

```
var mongoose = require("./db");
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema)
var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.save(function(err, cat){});
```

**The problem** here is:

How can I know and wait until the connection has been established, cos the save can be executed before the connection established which leads to an error.

Could anyone show me the correct way to use mongoose for this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm wondering about the same thing...